# How to clear the Azure AppInsight Data

Tags: azure

Wanted to find out how do i clear the Data from Azure AppInsight ?

Looked at the Azure portal, but could not find any options to clear.

Answer (score 16):

It is now possible with the release of the Purge API :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/components/purge

Comment: Better explanation of how "Purge" can be done is given here https://sanganakauthority.blogspot.com/2019/06/how-to-delete-or-purge-azure.html

Comment: Purge is the recommended way. Thanks this helped.

Answer (score 6):

That is not possible.

The only way to do that is to delete the entire Application Insights service configuration through the portal. [image]

And currently Application Insights has 7 days retention policy, so all data will be deleted automatically in 7 days.

Comment: Data is kep for 90 days: 'Raw data points (that is, items that you can query in Analytics and inspect in Search) are kept for up to 90 days' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/application-insights/app-insights-data-retention-privacy

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to delete azure application insights data now using Purge API.